# One object per distinct field / value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, distinct-values

I have this schema that represents a "File object" :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59f7184aedd1712cdd6a148a"),
"file" : {
    "part" : ".part000010",
    "creation_time" : "2017-10-26T14:01:42.309597",
    "archive_time" : "2017-10-30T12:17:14.770871",
    "inode" : 18644328,
    "size" : 733326,
    "tags" : null,
    "group" : "ssc_hpci",
    "uuid" : "408bf97c-bd6c-11e7-a854-de7a7d6f0f6c",
    "filename" : "build/hpca/base_library.zip",
    "owner" : "anl001",
    "gid" : 66026,
    "uid" : 66799,
    "checksum" : null,
    "symlink" : false
},
"archivename" : "build",
...
}
```

Many files will have the same archivename.

I need one object per *distinct* archivename. Obj1 would have an archive named "build", Obj2 an archive named "build1", etc.

Projection is not suitable for this, aggregate neither.

I'm using pymongo.

Comment: Could you add the sql query? *Many files will have the same archivename.* and *Obj1 would have an archive named "build", Obj2 an archive named "build1", etc.* is quite confusing. To me "build" and "build1" are not the same. May be the sql can shed some light.

Comment: Many objects will have the same field/value. In this case it's archivename. I need one object per distinct archivename value. Thanks. Feel free to edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. If you are happy with any object from the ones with the same archivename, aggregation is the way to go. Group by the field then project first document from the array.

Comment: @Pobe if the query is "very easy to do in SQL" then you should include it in your question so we have some reference on what you actually require.

Comment: Actually it was not that intuitive in MySQL, I though so and I needed a FOR loop. Which is what I will be using if there's no answer.